# How do I cast my array of arrays as a [[Double]] in Swift 3.0?

Tags: arrays, swift3

In Swift 2.3 I am able to take a `[String:AnyObject]` and cast it as! `[[Double]]`. However, using the same object in Swift 3.0, I am unable to cast it as a `[[Double]]`. When I cast it instead as a `[[AnyObject]]` or `[[Any]]`, loop through and try and convert, I get the following error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10783ec08) to 'NSNumber' (0x106e47320).

The following code works in my Swift 2.3 implementation, but NOT Swift 3.0

```
func extractCoordinatesForArea() {
    // This first line is where it crashes
    let theArraysOfCoordinates = myObject.geoArea!["geometry"]!["coordinates"] as! [[Double]]
    var newArea:[CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
    for coordArray in theArraysOfCoordinates {
        // x is LONG, LAT
        let x = [coordArray[0], coordArray[1]]
        // Reverse the coordinates because they are stored as LONG, LAT on the server
        let y = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(x[1],x[0])
        print(y)
        newArea.append(y)
    }
}
```

While the error makes sense, I cannot seem to get this to work after having explicitly declared the type or converting in the for loop. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to break the first statement like this.

```
if let geometryDic = myObject.geoArea["geometry"] as? [String:Any], 
   let coordinatesArray = geometryDic["coordinates"] as? [Any] {
   let theArraysOfCoordinates = coordinatesArray.first as? [[Double]] {
    var newArea:[CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
    for coordArray in theArraysOfCoordinates {
        //There is no need to create another array X you can directly use coordArray
        // Reverse the coordinates because they are stored as LONG, LAT on the server
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordArray[1],coordArray[0])
        print(coordinate)
        newArea.append(coordinate)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot! Had to cast theArraysOfCoordinates as? [[AnyObject]] first, then created theArrayOfCoordinate = theArraysOfCoordinates[0] as! [[Double]]

Comment: That means `geometryDic["coordinates"]` contains array with 2 nested array and you haven't show your response, check the edited answer, batter to use first property of array instead of subscript with index `0` this will cause you crash if array is empty.